# Работа с обектами и массивами JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Имеется такой объект:

```
Object {managers: Object, groups: Object}
groups{
    group_0:"Отдел продаж"
    group_20691:"Отдел продаж 2"
    group_22578:"Отдел продаж 3"
    group_38934:"Производство"
    group_40083:"PR отдел"
}

managers{
    275198:{
        active:true
        group:"group_40083"
        id:"275198"
        is_admin:"Y"
        login:"kolpa4kov@gmail.com"
        option:"Алексей Колпаков Get8"
        status:"OK"
        title:"Алексей Колпаков Get8"
    }
    306202:{
        active:true
        group:"group_0"
        id:"306202"
        is_admin:"Y"
        login:"altastra@gmail.com"
        option:"Александра"
        status:"OK"
        title:"Алексей Колпаков Get8"
    }
    ...
}
```

где в `groups` ключи  `group_0,group_20691` и т.д. равны значениям `managers['group']`.
Надо сформировать такой объект

```
manager{
    ["PR отдел"]=array({'group_40083','Алексей Колпаков GET8'},{'...','...'},...)
    ["Отдел продаж"]=array({'group_0','Иван'},{'...','...'},...)........
}
```

где менеджеры будут разбиты по отделам

Comment: приведите пример объекта текстом, возможно не все 200 свойств. А так же поясните в массив какого вида вам надо преобразовать, приведенный код непонятен. То ли вы хотите несколько массивов, то ли на самом деле вам нужен не массив а объект с полями

Comment: phpmix... @Grundy, он хочет объект, в котором ключами являются имена групп, а значениями массивы чего-то типа тех объектов, которые сейчас в members (возможно, не со всеми полями, возможно, в виде массива из двух элементов). Но при таком качестве вопроса у меня совершенно нет желания помогать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну я примерно понял что там надо, но самому эти объекты вбивать чтобы попробовать - как-то лень

Comment: сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/ajax/get_managers_with_group/",
    type:"POST",
    data:{},
    dataType:"json"
}).success(function(result) {
    var managers = {};
    for (groupId in result.groups) {
        managers[result.groups[groupId]] = [];
        for (managerId in result.managers) {
            if (result.managers[managerId].group == groupId) {
                managers[result.groups[groupId]].push(result.managers[managerId]);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(managers);
});
```

Comment: если бежать сразу по менеджерам, то по группам бежать не надо, можно просто к нужному свойству обращаться :)

Answer (score 0):

Так как соответствие прямое и поле `group` у менеджера соответствует ключу в объекте groups, то для решения достаточно пробежаться по всем менеджерам получить по полю - название группы, оно же будет полем конечного объекта и сохранить текущий объект.

Например:

```
var manager = Object.values(data.managers).reduce(function(acc, cur){
    var group = data.groups[cur.group];
    if(!acc[group]) acc[group]=[];
    //acc[group].push(cur); // если нужен полностью объект менеджера
    //acc[group].push([cur.group,cur.title]); //если значением должен будть массив
    acc[group].push({[cur.group]:cur.title});//для объектов вида {'group_40083':'Алексей Колпаков GET8'}
    return acc;
},{});
```

Comment: Grundy спасибо большое за ответ , вникать не буду в него. Но у меня получилось уже это сделать